# Find the equation of the normal to the curve

Tags: calculus

Good day everyone.

The normal to the curve $y=x^2-2x$ at a point P is parallel to the straight line $y=-2x+5$ .Find the equation of the normal to the curve at point P.

What does it question mean? Please explain it to me...What's the difference between normal and parallel? I am not asking for working but I just need to understand this question. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **normal** to the curve $y=f(x)$ at the point $(a,f(a))$ is the line through $(a,f(a))$ which is *perpendicular* to the tangent line at $(a,f(a))$.

Comment: Thanks sir I appreciate your effort in replying me thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome. For the rest, you will need to know the relationship between the slopes of perpendicular lines, and not much else.

Comment: The tangent line to the curve $y=x^2-2x$ at the point $(a,a^2-2a)$ has slope $2a-2$ (standard differentiation). So, if $2a-2\ne 0$, then the normal at $(a,a^2-2a)$ has slope $\frac{1}{2a-2}$.

Comment: We were told that the normal is parallel to the line $y=-2x+5$. That line has slope $-2$, so the normal has slpe $-2$. so the tangent line (perpendicular to the normal( has slope $\frac{-1}{-2}$, that is, $\frac{1}{2}$. It follows that $2a-2=\frac{1}{2}$. Solve for $a$. Now you know the point $P$, and you know the slope of the normal, so you can find the equation of the normal. Their version is a bit different, it says the slope of the normal times the slope of the tangent is $-1$, because these lines are perpendicular. So $(-2)(2a-2)=-1$. Solve for $a$.

Comment: Thank you sir Andre! I got the answer! Thank you really much! Basically it is just that $1/2=2x-2$ Just that the book does it differently! Haha thank you really much sir! Now I got the answer! Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. I recommend using $a$, or some other letter, not $x$, for the $x$-coordinate of the unknown point $P$. In my experience, that helps students with the logic of the argument, using $x$ can cause confusion.

Comment: If only I could contact you somewhere whenever I have problems because this site has a lot of random people here in which I might not ever see you again haha!

Comment: There are many very experienced people on this site. If you ask a clear question, you will likely receive an answer quite quickly.

Comment: Thank you again and I'm really hoping to meet you again sir! ^_^

Answer (score 2):

The [normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_(geometry)) to a curve at a point is the line/direction that is perpendicular to the tangent line of the curve at that point.

Comment: Thank you sir I appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 1):

A line perpendicular to tangent line is called a normal. So for the given curve a normal at a particular point P is parallel to $y=-2x+5$ which means the equation of normal and the line $y=-2x+5$ has the same slope that is -2. So now you have to find the equation of normal at P.

Comment: Sir I think your answer makes me understand the most. I still have 3 questions sir, what is the gradient? what is the gradient of the normal at P? what is the gradient of the tangent at P? How do they differ? Sorry, I just need to understand it more! >.<

Comment: gradient is operation just like differentiation where partial derivatives are used. You apply this operator to any function (having some restrictions). So here "Normal" and "Tangent" at P are functions for which you have to find the gradient. So here is the formula to apply gradient to a partcular function $\nabla f=\frac {\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac {\partial f}{\partial y}+\frac {\partial f}{\partial z}$ where $\nabla$ denotes gradient operation. Note the derivatives are partial that is with respect to x ,y and z respectively.